# What's the meaning of /gi in a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I see an line in my JavaScript code like this:

```
var regex = /[^\w\s]/gi;
```

What's the meaning of this `/gi` in the regex?

Other part I can understand as it accepts a group of word and spaces, but not `/gi`.

Comment: Actually, it matches a *single* "non-word", non-whitespace character `[^A-Za-z0-9_\s]`.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)

i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
```

In your case though `i` is immaterial as you dont capture `[a-zA-Z]`.

For input like `!@#$` if `g` modifier is not there regex will return first match `!`[**See here**](https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/55).

If `g` is there it will return the whole or whatever it can match.[**See here**](https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/56)

Answer (score 50):

The beginning and ending `/` are called delimiters. They tell the interpreter where the regex begins and ends. Anything *after* the closing delimiter is called a "modifier," in this case `g` and `i`.

The `g` and `i` modifiers have these meanings:

- `g` = global, match all instances of the pattern in a string, not just one
- `i` = case-insensitive (so, for example, `/a/i` will match the string `"a"` or `"A"`.

In the context you gave (`/[^\w\s]/gi`), the `i` is meaningless, because there are no case-specific portions of the regex.